# Running Flutter Web integration tests inside gitlab (probably github too) Ubuntu VM fails because of Chromedriver

Tags: ubuntu, gitlab, integration-testing, flutter-web, flutterdriver

I am trying to run integration tests for Web inside gitlab VM.
The VM is running Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS.
Chromedriver is launched with this command line:

```sh
chromedriver -port=4444 --enable-chrome-logs
```

The error from the chromedriver output is:

```
[0131/212240.342700:ERROR:sandbox_linux.cc(377)] InitializeSandbox() called with multiple threads in process gpu-process.
[0131/212240.347411:ERROR:command_buffer_proxy_impl.cc(125)] ContextResult::kTransientFailure: Failed to send GpuControl.CreateCommandBuffer.
[0131/212241.926360:INFO:CONSOLE(65)] "Installed new service worker.", source: http://localhost:8080/ (65)
[0131/212242.084358:ERROR:broker_posix.cc(46)] Received unexpected number of handles
```

Using chrome 97 or 97 along with chromedriver 97 or 98 gives the same error.

Flutter integration tests is launch using this command:

```sh
flutter drive --driver=test_driver/integration_test.dart --target=integration_test/app_test.dart -d web-server --headless
```

**InitializeSandbox() called with multiple threads in process** is know issue and is fixable using the flag --disable-gpu but until know, i haven't found any solution to disable gpu from within the Flutter CLI or by configuring the FlutterDriver.

Any idea on how to solve this problem?
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the --release flag has to be given to the command line.
So the command should look like:

```
flutter drive --driver=test_driver/integration_test.dart --target=integration_test/app_test.dart -d web-server --release
```